# Problemas con Haskell en VSCode. No me autocompleta

Tags: visual-studio, vscode, haskell, autocompletar

Estoy aprendiendo **Haskell** y la función de autocompletar no me funciona.
Tengo la **versión 8.6.5 de Haskell**, estoy en **Windows** y en Visual Studio Code tengo instaladas las extensiones Haskell y Haskell Syntax Highlighting.
Primero no me marcaba las palabras reservadas porque tenía la versión 8.0.1 de Haskell. Ahora me marca algunas palabras pero las sugerencias y autocompletar no.

A alguno le pasó o sabe como solucionar eso?

Comment: Si tienes problemas con tu código o la sintaxis añade la información para que los usuarios puedan ver donde esta el fallo.

Comment: Ya que no podemos reproducir exáctamente tu problema, necesitamos que nos des cuanta más información mejor. ¿Cómo has instalado ghc (instalador, chocolatey, ghcup,...)?¿Usas también cabal o stack? Añade un listado del directorio `%APPDATA%\Code\User\globalStorage\haskell.haskell`. Para las sugerencias se usa el `haskell-language-server` que descarga e instala la extensión en el directorio anterior. ¿Tienes algún otro `haskell-language-server` instalado? Si tenías instalada la versión 8.0.1, es posible que tuvieras una versión incompatible del hls.